# Numbers 21:8 - real fiery serpent or manufactured?

Tags: numbers, literary-criticism

**Numbers 21:8**

> And the LORD said unto Moses: 'Make thee a fiery serpent, and set it upon a pole; and it shall come to pass, that every one that is bitten, when he seeth it, shall live.'
>
> ח  וַיֹּאמֶר יְהוָה אֶל-מֹשֶׁה, עֲשֵׂה לְךָ שָׂרָף, וְשִׂים אֹתוֹ,
> עַל-נֵס; וְהָיָה, כָּל-הַנָּשׁוּךְ, וְרָאָה אֹתוֹ, וָחָי.

Did Moses take a snake (once alive now dead) and put it on a pole or did he create something that looked like a snake and place it on a pole?  What is this fiery serpent?

Comment: Related question: [Moses' manufacture of the “bronze serpent” - what bronze?](http://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/13387/moses-manufacture-of-the-bronze-serpent-what-bronze)

Answer (score 4):

Verse 9 clarifies that it was a BRONZE serpent that was made, in the NIV. In many other translations ti is also worded as **bronze**, but in some, as **brass**.